# How to make my text margin smaller without moving it downward?

Tags: html, css, margin

I’m doing a project for freecodecamp where I need to make a project similar to [this example](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNqgVx).

My problem is the part at the bottom with the unordered list and the heading above it. What css can make the heading margin align the same way as in the example? I’ve tried using `margin` but that changed the margin vertically, not just left and right.

Current code:

```html
<div id=“timeline”>
  <h4>Here's a timeline of Dr. Borlaug's life</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>example</li>
    <li>example</li>
    <li>example</li>
    <li>example</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If there’s anything extra I’m missing let me know and I’ll specify.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code so that I can help you solve this. As I cant see your code id just have to guess how to fix the issue. Here is the help pages guidelines on asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alright, I put my current HTML in

Comment: Ok ive answered as best I can with the limited code you provided. Its a bit bear but it follows the exact same method used in the example site you provided

Comment: Note that `margin` is shorthand for all four directional properties; `margin: 5px;` will apply `5px` of margin in *all four cardinal directions*. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this but if you are trying to match the example site you provided then your CSS and HTML should look something like this:

```
<div id=“timeline”>
  <ul>
    <h4>Here's a timeline of Dr. Borlaug's life</h4>
    <li>example</li>
    <li>example</li>
    <li>example</li>
    <li>example</li>
  </ul>
</div>


ul {
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Example of the code in use: https://jsfiddle.net/o96uayxc/1/

The folks at freeCodeCamp have applied a max-width to the list and then used `margin: 0 auto;` to center the element. This is because a margin with the value of auto fills the empty space equally on either side of the element. Importantly the heading is inside the list element in their example which keeps it within that max-width. The element text is left aligned which ensures it all aligns equally.